# Add phpmailer to HTML form

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I add a phpmailer with SMTP to my site. I have made a phpmailer file, and have done all the necessary coding what was needed. Now I need to know how to correctly add my phpmiler.php to my index.html so I can use my email form.

my phpmailer.php :

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'assets/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'assets/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'assets/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'test';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'test';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'test';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('test');
    $mail->addAddress('test');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('test', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

I tested the php file, everything works, I use TEST in personal information fields.

My HTML form:

```
<div class="block">
    <h2>Send message</h2>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

How do I make this work so that it takes email, text and subject into my phpmailer.php and send the message throw HTML form?
Thanks and sorry for my bad language, not my native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need change `<form>` to

```
<form action="/maybepath/phpmailer.php" method="POST" >
```

Second you need change phpmailer.php to get data from $_POST and put it in proper place. Try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give your form the appropriate action attr to point to your php file
2. In the php file substitude hard coded values to values gotten from the $_POST array - the keys would correspond to the name attr in your html
   example: $_POST['mail'] in the php file would hold the value from input with name attribute set to 'mail'